# Accessing model field attributes in Django

Tags: python, django, models

I have a model in Django 1.2.4:

```
class MyModel():
    foo = IntegerField(verbose_name="bar")

    def printFoo(self):
        print("Value of %s is %d" % (foo.verbose_name, foo))
```

I'm trying to get both the value and verbose name of a field. How can I do this?

I've looked at `myModel._meta.fields`, but I'm not sure if that's the way to go.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Probably like this:

```
MyModel._meta.get_field('foo').verbose_name
```

See [How can I programmatically obtain the max_length of a Django model field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829216/how-can-i-programmatically-obtain-the-max-length-of-a-django-model-field/1829286#1829286) for a very similar question.