# Django - ModelForm with fields derived from ForeignKey attributes

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Consider the following model

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name   = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author) 

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

I want a form to enter a book & author name (both as text input). I don't want a `ModelChoiceField` for Author. If the author doesn't exist, I'll create it in my view. I can achieve that by [declaratively defining](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields) author_name field & it's max_length like this:

```
class BookForm(ModelForm):
    author_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ['name']
```

How can I avoid hard-coding the max_length for `author_name` in BookForm? Can I deduce it from the linked Author model somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to: [programmatically obtain the max_length of a Django model field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1829286/3096768):

To obtain the `max_length` of a Model's field,

You can use `Author._meta.get_field('name').max_length`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [TextField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.TextField)?

Please see: [Django CharField vs TextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354588/django-charfield-vs-textfield)

ps. if this is not a good idea, please do not downvote me. I tried to add comment as suggestion, but I don't have enough points to do so :(

Comment: OK, no downvotes but this answer isn't correct. I don't want to remove the `max_length` restriction, rather I want to have the same restriction on my model fields & form fields without repeating the constant `max_length`.